# Youtube API View count for Category

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I get the total youtube video view count for videos in a specific category for a date range?
I thought of using the videos/list [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos] and just iterating through that to get the total count but the filtering is only allowing to at best to get the most popular videos.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *statistics* part of the Youtube API which contains the *viewCount*. You can retrieve the number of times the video has been viewed using `statistics.viewCount`. For the `date range`, you can include the [order](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) parameter `date` to specifies the method that will be used to order resources. Resources are sorted in reverse chronological order based on the date they were created.

Here a sample request for statistics:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Q5mHPo2yDG8&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Sample response:

```
"statistics": {
"viewCount": unsigned long,
"likeCount": unsigned long,
"dislikeCount": unsigned long,
"favoriteCount": unsigned long,
"commentCount": unsigned long
},
```